# How to migrate multiple SSH certificates to a different computer?

Tags: ssh

How to migrate multiple SSH certificates to a different computer?

I have generated multiple SSH crtificates (key pairs) on computer A and copied the `.ssh` directory including

- the default key pair `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` and
- the second pair `id_rsa_1` and `id_rsa_1.pub` and
- the configuration file `config`

on my USB drive.

How to duplicate the same SSH setting on a different computer B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy your `.ssh` directory to your homedir on computer B.

---

All the files you listed are completely self-contained; they are not tied to any system property or additional configuration. `id_rsa` contains RSA parameters in a standard format, nothing more. `config` is a text file containing your settings which you yourself can edit. They can be copied between systems freely.